# Are Route names supposed to be unique?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Using `react-router v0.12.4`.

Are Route names supposed to be unique? The following doesn't seem to work.

```
<Route name='app' path='/' handler={MainApp} >
    // instead of DefaultRoute, we use path matching
    <Route path="/" name="dashboard" handler={Dashboard}>
        <DefaultRoute name="main" handler={DashboardMain}/>
        <Route name='settings' handler={DashboardSettings} />
    </Route>

    <Route name='settings' handler={AppSettings} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Sorry to be that guy, but have you tried changing the route names and seeing if it works?

Comment: Yeah. Changing route names work. But I wanted to clarify this. I didn't want to spam `react-router` issues on GitHub.

Comment: Well it actually wouldn't be a bad issue to report for documentation.  They don't mention whether it's required to be unique or not so that would be helpful for them to advertise.  I can see why you would expect it not to be since there's cascading.

Comment: tracking issue: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/890

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/890#issuecomment-76475626, a maintainer has clarified that Route names are unique:

> Yes, they are supposed to be unique. We used to warn you about it.. we
>   should probably still do that.